# Searching through multiple rows and columns of a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table with multiple rows and columns. I wrote a function that is currently searching through only the first and last columns of my table, however I am not sure why the middle columns are being skipped over. I tried adding another for loop and got an error.

```js
function function2(){
          var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
          var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          var table = document.getElementById("table2c");
          var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
          var td, tdArr, i, j;
        
          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            tdArr = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (j = 0; j < tdArr.length; j++){
              td = tdArr [j];
              if (td) {
              if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          }
        }
       }
```

```html
This is my table: 
   <table className="table table-bordered" id="table2c">
                      <tbody>
                      <tr>
                      <th> Header Name: </th>
                      <th> Description: </th>
                      <th> Value: </th>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> Authorization </td>
                      <td> security token </td>
                      <td> To be supplied  </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> Content-Type </td>
                      <td> body of the request </td>
                      <td> applicaiton </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> API-KEY </td>
                      <td>  ID </td>
                      <td> To be supplied </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> correlation </td>
                      <td> Unique identifier </td>
                      <td> e.g. control number </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> name </td>
                      <td> system name  </td>
                      <td> One of: </td>
                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Comment: what is the wanted result? hide all rows without some search result?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes that is the result, which is functioning right now, but its only searching through the first and last column, I want to be able to search for data in the middle column as well

Answer (score 2):

add break here
if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
    break;
}
You need to stop the second loop once youfind a result, otherwise if the element is not found in the third column it will hide the entire row

```js
function function2(){
          var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
          var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          var table = document.getElementById("table2c");
          var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
          var td, tdArr, i, j;
        
          for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            tdArr = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (j = 0; j < tdArr.length; j++){
              td = tdArr [j];
              if (td) {
              if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                break;
              } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          }
        }
       }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<button onclick="function2()">search</button>
This is my table: 
   <table className="table table-bordered" id="table2c">
                      <tbody>
                      <tr>
                      <th> Header Name: </th>
                      <th> Description: </th>
                      <th> Value: </th>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> Authorization </td>
                      <td> security token </td>
                      <td> To be supplied  </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> Content-Type </td>
                      <td> body of the request </td>
                      <td> applicaiton </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> API-KEY </td>
                      <td>  ID </td>
                      <td> To be supplied </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> correlation </td>
                      <td> Unique identifier </td>
                      <td> e.g. control number </td>
                      </tr>
        
                      <tr>
                      <td> name </td>
                      <td> system name  </td>
                      <td> One  </td>
                      </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Comment: thank you, that worked for the middle column but now the last column is no longer included in the search @ramSegev

Comment: i fixed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add break; to exist for loop if match found.

```js
    function function2() {
        var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var table = document.getElementById("table2c");
        var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var td, tdArr, i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            tdArr = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (j = 0; j < tdArr.length; j++) {
                td = tdArr[j];
                if (td) {
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                        break;
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" /> <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" onclick="function2()" />
<table className="table table-bordered" id="table2c">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th> Header Name: </th>
        <th> Description: </th>
        <th> Value: </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> Authorization </td>
        <td> HMAC security token </td>
        <td> To be supplied by APIGEE </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> Content-Type </td>
        <td> Media type of the body of the request </td>
        <td> applicaiton/xml </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> X-AMEX-API-KEY </td>
        <td> HMAC ID </td>
        <td> To be supplied by APIGEE </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> correlation_id </td>
        <td> Unique identifier to track the consumer request </td>
        <td> e.g. Process control number </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> originator_name </td>
        <td> Originating consumer system name  </td>
        <td> One of: GCAP, GDE </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop from the second row, because a find would vanish the table head. Then you could switch off all rows in advance and remove `'none'` if a found value is in the row. Break then as well.

```js
function function2() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
      table = document.getElementById("table2c"),
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
      td, tdArr, i, j;

  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
    tdArr = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < tdArr.length; j++) {
      td = tdArr[j];
      if (td && td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" onchange="function2()">
<table className="table table-bordered" id="table2c">
  <tbody>
    <tr><th> Header Name: </th><th> Description: </th><th> Value: </th></tr>
    <tr><td> Authorization </td><td> HMAC security token </td><td> To be supplied by APIGEE </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Content-Type </td><td> Media type of the body of the request </td><td> applicaiton/xml </td></tr>
    <tr><td> X-AMEX-API-KEY </td><td> HMAC ID </td><td> To be supplied by APIGEE </td></tr>
    <tr><td> correlation_id </td><td> Unique identifier to track the consumer request </td><td> e.g. Process control number </td></tr>
    <tr><td> originator_name </td><td> Originating consumer system name </td><td> One of: GCAP, GDE </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here's an implementation using a functionnal approach with some ES6 features ([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method):

```js
const filter = () => {

  const input = document.querySelector('#myInput');
  const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  
  const table = document.querySelector('#table2c');
  const trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(:first-child)');
  
  // loop through all <tr> except the first one (header)
  trs.forEach(tr => {
  
    // reduce all the row's content (header, description and value) to a single string)
    const content = [...tr.children].reduce((content, td) => content + ' ' + td.textContent, '')
    
    // search if the filter is in content
    if(content.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
    
      tr.style.display = "";
    
    } else {

      tr.style.display = "none";
    
    }

  });

}

// add an event listener to the input element
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filter);
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />

<table className="table table-bordered" id="table2c">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Header Name: </th>
      <th> Description: </th>
      <th> Value: </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Authorization </td>
      <td> HMAC security token </td>
      <td> To be supplied by APIGEE </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Content-Type </td>
      <td> Media type of the body of the request </td>
      <td> applicaiton/xml </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> X-AMEX-API-KEY </td>
      <td> HMAC ID </td>
      <td> To be supplied by APIGEE </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> correlation_id </td>
      <td> Unique identifier to track the consumer request </td>
      <td> e.g. Process control number </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> originator_name </td>
      <td> Originating consumer system name </td>
      <td> One of: GCAP, GDE </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```